# How to upgrade an application inside a Docker image

Tags: docker

I am very new to this docker thing, and as such might not have been able to frame my search good enough to find this answer. However I am trying to build a test image which would contain a few test applications,

But I see a problem there.
If I commit them all to one image and then need to upgrade one of the applications I would need to rebuild me entire Image again and the redistribute this image to all remotes (Is this correct ?).

Do I then used data containers for my applications and just have a linux image ?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your single container into multiple containers each with one Microservice.

> Microservices is an approach to application development in which a large application is built as a suite of modular services. Each module supports a specific business goal and uses a simple, well-defined interface to communicate with other modules.

In you case you can start putting each application into one container.

Example:

You have a web application, first step would be having a container for webapp and another for the database.

Volumes are used for persistent data, Like your Database files that you want to keep after removing the container. It's not a good practice to have your entire app in these volumes.

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear on docker terms. I have made a Linux image ment for running my application. When you say container do you then mean a data container which i mount inside the Docker Image ?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about data containers. Your application has many parts, Like a Database, a web server and etc, You better use a separate container for each part. Volumes are used for persistent data, Like your Database files that you want to keep after removing the container. It's not a good practice to have your entire app in these volumes.

Comment: Ok I this is how I understand it. I'll take each of my Test applications and put them into their own Image based on my base Linux image. Is that correct ?

Comment: That's correct. Each application will have it's own image.